# How long will it take to completely run out of power a Li-ion battery of 3.7V and 1000mAh, if the load consumes 16mA?

Tags: batteries, amperage, time, power-consumption

I'm trying to determine the exact time that run out power a Li-ion battery of 3.7V and 1000mAh. I'm using a load of 16mA.

If I use the theoretical calculus:

$$time=\frac{1000mAh}{16mA} = 62.5 \;hours$$

Then I proceeded to do the practical test of this calculus, but my circuit take more than 90 hours and the battery is still alive. Can someone explain to me why this happens? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 1000mAh figure is likely what the battery is *rated* for, not what it is necessarily capable of. What the battery is capable of is a complex relationship between its age, number of charge/discharge cycles, how discharged the battery gets every time, etc.

Comment: Calculation is right. Batt has different mAh depending on discharge current. Normally, manufacturer give best case mAh and user may get slightly lower rating under actual use.  Another factor. Is the load constant current? Does it take less current when voltage drop?

Comment: What is the voltage of your battery now?  You may have drawn it down more than what is normally considered wise or useful, and if your load is ohmic your current draw may be proportionally reduced.

Comment: Note that a li-ion battery is considered empty at 3.6V (or around 2.5V under load). A battery that is below 3.5V without load is considered potentially damaged and a battery that is below 2.5V without load should not be recharged. So that 1000mAh is rated for the battery to go from 4.2V to 3.6V.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. In fact, you're doing exactly right by not stressing your battery. You've run across a couple of things. First, Ah capacity is always sized somewhat conservatively, so that people don't get disappointed and try a competitor's battery. This is counterbalanced by the desire to claim as much capacity as possible so people don't go buy a competitor's battery. The other factor is that, as current decreases the efficiency of the battery increases. With low current demands the internal chemistry can produce more power with, among other things, less wasted heat.

I'm a bit surprised that your efficiency gain is this large, though.

Comment: I should add that temperature must be factored in: the battery's capacity will change with temperature. Also, you can overcharche a battery: if the charge voltage should be 4.1V you may try and put 4.2V (dangerous!!) and it will give you more juice, at the cost of reducing your battery life. This could happen if you've got a charger for the wrong chemistry, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show a link to the data sheet, but the 1000mAh rating for your battery is likely to be determined at a C rate something like 1C, C/5, or C/10.  Meaning, a 1 hour, 5 hour, or 10 hour discharge rate.  At a 60+ hour discharge rate you will see more usable capacity from the battery.  Hard to say whether it "should" be 50% more capacity without knowing more from the manufacturer.

The other possibility, is your load actually a constant current load on the battery?  Or is it something like constant resistance, constant power, constant average power with lots of spikiness, constant current into the "actual" load on the other side of a regulator which may have varying efficiency depending on battery voltage?

Comment: Yes, Matt B, I think you have the answer!  The rate of discharge has an effect on the measured capacity.  @user2404177 look up Peukert's law which is likely affecting your battery in this instance.